# How to print a parse tree using Bison?

Tags: bison, yacc, flex-lexer, parse-tree

I have implemented a parser but it does not print anything. If the given input is syntactically wrong, it does not print "Error" though I included it in the `yyerror()` routine. Also if the input is correct, it does not print the Parse tree. What might be the possible reason for this? I have put my `main()` in `.lex` file instead of in `.y` file. Is that the possible reason for that?
This is the main method:

```
int main( argc, argv )
int argc;
char **argv;
{
    ++argv, --argc; 
    if ( argc > 0 )
    yyin = fopen( argv[0], "r" );
    else
    yyin = stdin;     

    yyparse();
}
```

---

The grammar file is:

```
%{
#include "parser.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
%}

%union {
  char* a_variable;
  tree* a_tree;
}

%start file
%token <a_variable> TOKID TOKSEMICOLON TOLCOLON TOKCOMMA TOKUNRECOG TOKDOT TOKMINUS TOKCOLON
%type <a_tree> field file obj ID
%right TOKMINUS

%%

file      :     /*empty*/ { return NULL; }
      |     field file { printtree($1, 1);  }
  ;

field     : ID TOKCOLON field {$$ = make_op($1, ':', $3); }
  | ID TOKCOMMA field {$$ = make_op($1, ',', $3); }
  | obj { $$ = $1; }
  ;

obj       :     ID TOKSEMICOLON { $$ = make_op($1, ';', NULL); }
      ;

ID        :     TOKID { $$ = $1; }

%%

#include <stdio.h>
yyerror(char *str)
{
  fprintf(stderr,"error FAIL: %s\n",str);
}

int yywrap()
{
  return 1;
}
```

---

This is how my `.lex` file looks:

```
%{
/* need this for the call to atof() below */
#include <math.h>
#include "parser.h"
#include "idf.tab.h"
%}

DIGIT    [0-9]
ID       [a-zA-Z]*
%option noyywrap

%% 


{ID} |  
-?{DIGIT}+"."{DIGIT}* |    
-?{DIGIT}+      { yylval.a_variable = findname(yytext); return TOKID; }

";"           return TOKSEMICOLON;
":"           return TOKCOLON;
","           return TOKCOMMA;
"."           return TOKDOT;
"-"           return TOKMINUS; 
.           return TOKUNRECOG;
%%

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
++argv, --argc; 
if ( argc > 0 )
yyin = fopen( argv[0], "r" );
else
yyin = stdin;

yyparse();
}
```

Comment: Please show (at least) your `main ()` definition.  Otherwise there is no way to answer your question.

Comment: @TimLandscheidt I have included my `main()` definition now.

Comment: The basic approach in your `main` is okay, except for the lack of condition checking. What if the argument cannot be opened? You set `yyin` to a null pointer and call `yylex`.

Comment: Your `main` calls `yylex`, which is the scanner function generated by `lex`. `yylex` reads just a single token. You must call `yyparse`. !!!

Comment: @Kaz I modified it and called `yyparse()` instead of `yylex()` but still its not showing up anything

Comment: You will have to show more of your program. The `main` is fine now, except for the lack of error checking, the lack of a return value and the use of an outdated C dialect (old style declaration).

Comment: @Kaz I have posted my `.y` file below. Please have a look at it.

Comment: Please update the question - like I just did for you.  You can edit a question like that when it is your question.  Just don't destroy the integrity of the question if there are already answers in place.

Comment: What service from `<malloc.h>` are you using that is not made available by `<stdlib.h>`.  You shouldn't use `<malloc.h>` unless you know the answer to the question "What services does `<malloc.h>` provide that are not in `<stdlib.h>`?"

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for updating my question. I have now included my `.lex` file too. The code for building the parse tree using the function `malloc()` and that is the reason why I included `<malloc.h>`.

Comment: The declaration for `malloc()` et al is in `<stdlib.h>` and you don't need `<malloc.h>` unless you are tuning the allocation strategies for `malloc()` using the extra functions defined in `<malloc.h>` (other than `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `realloc()` and `free()`).  The core memory allocation routines are in `<stdlib.h>` and you don't normally need `<malloc.h>` as well.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ok. I removed `<malloc.h>`. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a [homework] tag missing from this?

Comment: @Kaz There was never a homework tag in this.

Answer (score 1):

The function `yylex()` is the lexical scanner, not the grammar parser; the parser is `yyparse()`.  So, update your program to call `yyparse()` instead of `yylex()`, leaving `yyparse()` to call `yylex()` when it needs a new token:

```
while (yyparse() != 0)
    ;
```

You might do printing of the parse tree in place of the empty loop body, or you might do your printing in a function called from the start rule in the grammar itself.

On a side-note, I cannot think of a good reason to use the K&R declaration of `main()`.  Always use `int main(int argc, char **argv)`.  And if you do use K&R notation, then you must return a value from `main()`, conventionally zero on success and non-zero on failure.  Although C99 permits you to omit the final return from `main()` (which is equivalent to `return 0;` in the sole very exceptional case of `main()`), I recommend including it.

---

#### Later notes

It's a good idea to make it easy for people to test what you're asking for help with.  Provide enough source to make it compilable.  Remove enough source to minimize the compilation effort.

It wasn't very hard to neutralize the various action functions in the grammar.  The `parser.h` file needed to contain something like `typedef struct tree tree;`.  And the grammar needed to be `idf.y`, so that `bison -d idf.y` would generate `idf.tab.h` and `idf.tab.c`.

One of the first things I do with a lexical analyzer is ensure it prints what it is doing. So, I modified the rules to do things like:

```
{ID} |  
-?{DIGIT}+"."{DIGIT}* |    
-?{DIGIT}+      { printf("ID or number: %s\n", yytext); /*yylval.a_variable = findname(yytext);*/ return TOKID; }

";"           { printf("Semi-colon\n"); return TOKSEMICOLON;}
":"           { printf("Colon\n"); return TOKCOLON;}
```

This fairly quickly showed me that you don't handle spaces or newlines very gracefully.  You probably need rules to do so (and those rules probably don't return to the grammar).

```
[ \t]         { printf("White space\n"); }
```

That needs to appear before the 'gobbling dot' rule, of course.

With that in place, I was able to run the program and get lexical output:

```
$ ./idf
abc ;
ID or number: abc
White space
Semi-colon

$
```

I typed `abc ;` at it and it identified those OK.  Since the grammar had no code left in the actions, there was no output from the grammar itself.  It would probably be worth compiling with `-DYYDEBUG` and setting `yydebug = 1;` in the `main()` function — you might need to add `extern int yydebug;` in the lexical analyzer source file since `main()` is there.

```
$ flex scanner.l
$ bison -d idf.y
$ gcc -DYYDEBUG -o idf idf.tab.c lex.yy.c
$ ./idf
Starting parse
Entering state 0
Reading a token: abc ;
ID or number: abc
Next token is token TOKID ()
Shifting token TOKID ()
Entering state 1
Reducing stack by rule 7 (line 32):
   $1 = token TOKID ()
-> $$ = nterm ID ()
Stack now 0
Entering state 5
Reading a token: White space
Semi-colon
Next token is token TOKSEMICOLON ()
Shifting token TOKSEMICOLON ()
Entering state 8
Reducing stack by rule 6 (line 29):
   $1 = nterm ID ()
   $2 = token TOKSEMICOLON ()
-> $$ = nterm obj ()
Stack now 0
Entering state 4
Reducing stack by rule 5 (line 26):
   $1 = nterm obj ()
-> $$ = nterm field ()
Stack now 0
Entering state 3
Reading a token: 
Now at end of input.
Reducing stack by rule 1 (line 20):
$
```

Now your problems are in the functions you've not shown.  Those are yours to solve.

Comment: I have updated it to `yyparse()` but still it isn't showing up any output.

Answer (score 1):

I am not so sure you can combine multiple rules into one like this:

```
{ID} |  -?{DIGIT}+"."{DIGIT}* |    -?{DIGIT}+      return TOKID;
```

lex is whitespace sensitive; I think it should be like this:

```
{ID} |
-?{DIGIT}+"."{DIGIT}* |
-?{DIGIT}+      return TOKID;
```

The `|` character is interpreted as a special kind of action which means "same action as that of the next line".  Within a pattern `|` denotes a regex branch. But you have all these spaces there.

Your comment matcher looks bogus:

```
"{"[\^{}}\n]*"}"     /* eat up one-line comments */
```

I think you wanted a negated character class here but you put an escape on the `^` character which simply causes `^` to be included in the character class.

What is the point of this:

```
"!"+"-"[\n] return TOKCOMMENT;
```

A sequence of `!` followed by - and newline is some kind of comment that you're not ignoring, but returning as a token, wha?

This parse rule can't work properly because of broken behavior in your lexer:

```
ID        :     TOKID { $$ = $1; }
```

The expression `$1` wants to access `yystack[<whatever>].a_variable` because you defined `TOKID` as having the `a_variable` semantic type. But your lex rule which produces `TOKID` does not put anything into `a_variable`. It just does `return TOKID;`, leaving that pointer to contain garbage.  Your lexer rule has to assign to `yylval.a_variable`.

Lex and Yacc are far less automatic than you make them out to be.

Comment: I made the changes suggested by you. Please let me know if it is fine now.

Comment: By the way, why are you tokenizing numbers to `TOKID`? You have a `TOKFLOAT` in your grammar file; should you not be using that for `{DIGIT}+[.]{DIGIT}+`?

Comment: I do not want to make the grammar look complex. That is reason why I am tokenizing numbers to `TOKID`. I can remove `TOKFLOAT`.